# What does area under this density plot gives me?

Tags: data-visualization, cumulative-distribution-function

I am new to data science and trying to grasp the concepts. I have a question in my exercise asking "what proportion of US states have populations larger than 10 million?". The density plot is shown below:
[image]

What I did was assumed the region to the right of 10 million on X-axis as a right angled triangle. Calculated it's approx area to be (0.5*20*0.5) which comes out to be `5`. Now what does this 5 represent? Shouldn't be the area of any part be less than 1 as the area under the curve should be `1`. This is what I understood by listening to some lectures on edx.

Comment: What happened to your x-axis? Seems a bit off.

Comment: It was an exercise question, I didn’t generate it.

Answer (score 1):

The area under a density curve should indeed sum up to a total of one, as you mentioned. For a general estimation a triangle seems a decent fit, but the problem in your calculation is that you forgot to scale the outcome of your calculation with the highest population of all states, in this case ~34 (eyeballing here).

This scaling step makes sure that your calculations using a density graph with an x-axis of physical meaning become agnostic to the actual unit of your x-axis.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So should I calculate base of the triangle as ((30/34)-(10/34)) for scaling purposes?